# Import data from Excel of type float to varchar in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel

I have a problem regarding importing data from Excel to SQL. In the import wizard in SQL, the datatype of the field/s is in float (because data contain purely numbers, IDNumber, BiometricNumber and BankAccountNumber) now the datatype of this fields in SQL is varchar and when ever I query or transfer the data to other table the format of value changes to float with e+ digit. Anyone?

Comment: have you tried playing around with "Format cells" in excel?

Comment: haven't but i give it a try thanks.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why a data element `BankAccountNumber` is of type `FLOAT`, consider that Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) SQL for Excel has but one numeric data type ;)

Comment: thanks I follow Mi Mee's advice and realize to change format of that certain column in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure you are using `IMEX=1` in the connection string and that the associated registry key values are set appropriately. For full details, see [this article](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/).

Personally, I've never had a problem with scientific notation but a few people have reported similar problems in comments so it might be worth trawling through them. Here's a couple I spotted:

> In SQL, `Format([COLUMN NAME], ‘@’) As [COLUMN NAME]`
>
> In Excel, column has to be formatted  (Format cells) as “general” (not
>   formatted as “text”).

I cannot vouch for them, though ;)

Comment: i have try both formatted as general and text, but MSSQL still set it as float!!!

Comment: @Huei: But have you set `IMEX=1`, set the registry settings as appropriate, etc? The link to the article is broken but googling "IMEX=1 " and my handle (OneDayWhen) should reveal more details e.g. here: http://www.instantpages.ltd.uk/ADODB_WP.htm

Answer (score 2):

I changed the data type of the excel column to 'Text' when it was 'General' and the 32 bit SQL Server Import Tool picked it up as an nvarchar.

Comment: didn't work..:(