# Why does a number imported to SQL Server from Excel contain the letter e?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I have got a excel sheet which inserts data in to SQL Server, but noticed for a particular field, the data is being inserted with e, this particular field is of type varchar and size 20.

Why is e being inserted when the actual data for these respective fields is 54607677038, 77200818179 and 9920996.

Help me out

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Data type for that Column in DB?

Comment: There is a place somewhere in your code where you convert a `double` to a `string` before inserting it into your database table. That is where you need to look.

Comment: Please extend your question to include details like: What is the value in Excel (I suspect a long string of digits, that Excel treats as a number)? How are you inserting from Excel into SqlServer?

Comment: @Thit varchar of size 50

Comment: @Hans added the details as per your request

Comment: [Good answer here, work for me!][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721851/how-to-import-data-from-excel-of-type-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server-2008/7722582#7722582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You* may think of '2007038971' as being just a string of numbers (some kind of article code, I guess). Excel just sees numbers and treats it as a numerical value. It probably is right aligned (default for numbers) and not left-aligned (default for strings).

When asked to store in as a string, it 'helpfully' formats that number into a string, thereby introducing that "e" notation (the value 2007038971 is about 2.00704 * 10^9).

You need to convince Excel that that code really is a string, maybe by adding a quote in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. When you read value from excel, then convert ToString() and insert into DB. Need to change relevant data type based on data in your excel.

```
 double doub = 2.00704e+009;
 string val = doub.ToString();
```

Comment: I just need a reason why is 'e' being inserted, not the solution to rectify it.